# FULL JOIN in the same table in SQL

Tags: sql, join, union

I am a new sql student and really need your help.
I have a table like this
[Raw Data and OutPut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULfEA.png)
There is a column named Scenario,
I want to bring the value of column I(May) from line 7 - 10 of Scenario = Fcst to new column and name it as FcstMay.
So my output should be looked like from line 13-18, and I marked Scenario = FvA

The dataset is very big, it may go up to 100k lines, I was thinking to use UNION but it could make my data is bigger.

Would really appreciate if you could help me or solve me how to work with this table. Example at https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vDB2wfwyxkcUHGJPvpmgmt/2

| State | Col1 | Col2 | Scenario | JAN | FEB | MAR | APR | May |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| California | T | Tcost | Act | $51.00 | $58.00 | $42.00 | $39.00 | $41.00 |
| California | CR | CR | Act | $95.00 | $31.00 | $40.00 | $26.00 | $37.00 |
| California | TCDP | ocos | Act | $45.00 | $58.00 | $30.00 | $28.00 | $23.00 |
| California | Revenue | Revenue | Act | $13.00 | $50.00 | $65.00 | $92.00 | $84.00 |
| California | T | Tcost | Fcst | $10.00 | $72.00 | $47.00 | $17.00 | $67.00 |
| California | CR | CR | Fcst | $57.00 | $49.00 | $94.00 | $12.00 | $75.00 |
| California | TCDP | ocos | Fcst | $46.00 | $13.00 | $98.00 | $62.00 | $84.00 |
| California | Oth | Oth | Fcst | $38.00 | $13.00 | $23.00 | $44.00 | $93.00 |

Comment: Could you paste the code that you have used so far, that would help to see where the issue is.

Comment: Please don't link to images in your question, paste the data as editable text into your question

Comment: Hi AlexanderP,

Here is my code: 
SELECT State, col1, col2, "FvA" AS scenario, Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, 0 as MayFcst from myTable
where scenario in ("Act")

union all

SELECT State, col1, col2, "FvA" AS scenario, 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , May AS MayFcst
from myTable
where scenario in ("Fcst")

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate a `FULL OUTER JOIN` in MySQL by consolidating (using `UNION ALL`) a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` with an anti-join. It's repetitive but it works.

With the right indexes it can even be fast.

For example:

```
select a.State, a.Col1, a.Col2, 'FvA' as Scenario,
  a.JAN, a.FEB, a.MAR, a.APR, a.May, b.May as MayFcst
from data a
left join data b on b.Col1 = a.Col1 and b.Scenario = 'Fcst'
where a.Scenario = 'Act'
union all
select b.State, b.Col1, b.Col2, 'FvA',
  null, null, null, null, null, b.May as MayFcst
from data b
left join data a on b.Col1 = a.Col1 and a.Scenario = 'Act'
where b.Scenario = 'Fcst'
and a.Col1 is null
```

Result:

```
State       Col1     Col2     Scenario  JAN     FEB     MAR     APR     May     MayFcst 
----------- -------- -------- --------- ------- ------- ------- ------- ------- ------- 
California  T        Tcost    FvA       $51.00  $58.00  $42.00  $39.00  $41.00  $67.00
California  CR       CR       FvA       $95.00  $31.00  $40.00  $26.00  $37.00  $75.00
California  TCDP     ocos     FvA       $45.00  $58.00  $30.00  $28.00  $23.00  $84.00
California  Revenue  Revenue  FvA       $13.00  $50.00  $65.00  $92.00  $84.00  null  
California  Oth      Oth      FvA       null    null    null    null    null    $93.00
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vDB2wfwyxkcUHGJPvpmgmt/3).